# How to create a dll like shell32.dll which contains Icons

Tags: vb.net

I am working on the Visual studio 2010. want to create a dll which contains icons just like shell32.dll. Can anyone guide me what I need to do. 
Purpose : I just want my fav icons bind with one dll and keep in my root drive and customize me all folder icons and I just need it ot contain Dll thats it.
I have not idea what and all efforted is needed, I am ready to put how much effort is needed. 
Any suggestion or comment is welcome.
I am not sure what detail is need so adding the picture of shell32.dll.

[image: Shell32.dll]

Comment: In the age of Windows 98 I have been using Microangelo Librarian for this. It was saving ICL files seeming to be plain resource-only DLLs as far as I can remember.

Comment: keyboardP
I have read the link that you mentioned but there is nothing specific about .net platform. Can you please help me specifically vb.net environment.

Comment: @Alix - Try this: http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm You can convert the code from C# to VB.NET here: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a [Resource-Only DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0.aspx).

From the link:

> To create a resource-only DLL, you create a new Win32 DLL (non-MFC)
>   project and add your resources to the project.
>
> - Select Win32 Project in the New Project dialog box and specify a DLL    project type in the Win32 Project Wizard.
> - Create a new resource script that contains the resources (such as a    string or a menu) for the DLL and save the .rc file.
> - On the Project menu, click Add Existing Item, and then insert the new    .rc file into the project.
> - Specify the /NOENTRY linker option. /NOENTRY prevents the linker from    linking a reference to _main into the DLL; this option is
>     required to    create a resource-only DLL.
> - Build the DLL.